# Metadict in ffmpeg does not have rotate information

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, rotation, video-processing

My aim is to extract frames out of a video but many times the frames are inverted. This is happening because "VideoCapture" in cv2 does read the rotate flag data present in the video metadata. I am running it on mac and installed "ffmpeg" package (5.0.1) using brew package manager. This is my code to check rotation present in a video using ffmpeg.

```
import ffmpeg 
import cv2   
import pprint 
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(depth=4)
def check_rotation(path_video_file):
    # this returns meta-data of the video file in form of a dictionary
    meta_dict = ffmpeg.probe(path_video_file)
    pp.pprint(meta_dict)

    # from the dictionary, meta_dict['streams'][0]['tags']['rotate'] is the key
    # we are looking for
    rotateCode = None
    if int(meta_dict['streams'][0]['tags']['rotate']) == 90:
        rotateCode = cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE
    elif int(meta_dict['streams'][0]['tags']['rotate']) == 180:
        rotateCode = cv2.ROTATE_180
    elif int(meta_dict['streams'][0]['tags']['rotate']) == 270:
        rotateCode = cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE

    return rotateCode
```

Here the meta_dict is supposed to have information about the rotation but it is not there.
printing out meta_dict gives:

```
{'format': {'bit_rate': '18498544',
            'duration': '3.584000',
            'filename': 'video.mp4',
            'format_long_name': 'QuickTime / MOV',
            'format_name': 'mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2',
            'nb_programs': 0,
            'nb_streams': 2,
            'probe_score': 100,
            'size': '8287348',
            'start_time': '0.000000',
            'tags': {'com.android.version': '11',
                     'compatible_brands': 'isommp42',
                     'creation_time': '2021-12-08T10:56:57.000000Z',
                     'major_brand': 'mp42',
                     'minor_version': '0'}},
 'streams': [{'avg_frame_rate': '990000/34997',
              'bit_rate': '18804651',
              'bits_per_raw_sample': '8',
              'chroma_location': 'left',
              'closed_captions': 0,
              'codec_long_name': 'H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10',
              'codec_name': 'h264',
              'codec_tag': '0x31637661',
              'codec_tag_string': 'avc1',
              'codec_type': 'video',
              'coded_height': 1080,
              'coded_width': 1920,
              'color_primaries': 'bt470bg',
              'color_range': 'pc',
              'color_space': 'bt470bg',
              'color_transfer': 'smpte170m',
              'display_aspect_ratio': '16:9',
              'disposition': {'attached_pic': 0,
                              'captions': 0,
                              'clean_effects': 0,
                              'comment': 0,
                              'default': 1,
                              'dependent': 0,
                              'descriptions': 0,
                              'dub': 0,
                              'forced': 0,
                              'hearing_impaired': 0,
                              'karaoke': 0,
                              'lyrics': 0,
                              'metadata': 0,
                              'original': 0,
                              'still_image': 0,
                              'timed_thumbnails': 0,
                              'visual_impaired': 0},
              'duration': '3.499700',
              'duration_ts': 314973,
              'extradata_size': 35,
              'field_order': 'progressive',
              'film_grain': 0,
              'has_b_frames': 0,
              'height': 1080,
              'id': '0x1',
              'index': 0,
              'is_avc': 'true',
              'level': 40,
              'nal_length_size': '4',
              'nb_frames': '99',
              'pix_fmt': 'yuvj420p',
              'profile': 'High',
              'r_frame_rate': '120/1',
              'refs': 1,
              'sample_aspect_ratio': '1:1',
              'side_data_list': [{...}],
              'start_pts': 3168,
              'start_time': '0.035200',
              'tags': {'creation_time': '2021-12-08T10:56:57.000000Z',
                       'handler_name': 'VideoHandle',
                       'language': 'eng',
                       'vendor_id': '[0][0][0][0]'},
              'time_base': '1/90000',
              'width': 1920},
             {'avg_frame_rate': '0/0',
              'bit_rate': '128986',
              'bits_per_sample': 0,
              'channel_layout': 'stereo',
              'channels': 2,
              'codec_long_name': 'AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)',
              'codec_name': 'aac',
              'codec_tag': '0x6134706d',
              'codec_tag_string': 'mp4a',
              'codec_type': 'audio',
              'disposition': {'attached_pic': 0,
                              'captions': 0,
                              'clean_effects': 0,
                              'comment': 0,
                              'default': 1,
                              'dependent': 0,
                              'descriptions': 0,
                              'dub': 0,
                              'forced': 0,
                              'hearing_impaired': 0,
                              'karaoke': 0,
                              'lyrics': 0,
                              'metadata': 0,
                              'original': 0,
                              'still_image': 0,
                              'timed_thumbnails': 0,
                              'visual_impaired': 0},
              'duration': '3.584000',
              'duration_ts': 172032,
              'extradata_size': 2,
              'id': '0x2',
              'index': 1,
              'nb_frames': '168',
              'profile': 'LC',
              'r_frame_rate': '0/0',
              'sample_fmt': 'fltp',
              'sample_rate': '48000',
              'start_pts': 0,
              'start_time': '0.000000',
              'tags': {'creation_time': '2021-12-08T10:56:57.000000Z',
                       'handler_name': 'SoundHandle',
                       'language': 'eng',
                       'vendor_id': '[0][0][0][0]'},
              'time_base': '1/48000'}]}
```

Can someone please help me to find if rotation is present in a video?

Comment: What's in the `side_data_list`?

Comment: @kesh hey, thanks it has rotation information, this pretty print only has hidden this info :D Thank you so much.

Comment: I have the same problem. In previous releases of FFMpeg the rotation informaiton was a  part of `tags` array, but with the most recent release (ffmpeg version N-109270-g39dc9a7421) it is not there.